# Почему размер панели не регулируется параметром .setSize()?

Tags: java, awt, jpanel

Почему размер панели не регулируется параметром .setSize()?
У меня панель в панели content и pane. Content использует BorderLayout, а вторая - GridLayout. Как сделать так, чтоб центральная часть окна была меньше, чем остальные?

content.add(pane, "Center");
pane.setSize(30, 30); размер панели в данном случае не меняется.

Comment: Пример кода киньте что есть.

Comment: Смею предположить что скорее всего менять нужно соотношение свободного пространства у layout менеджера.